# "onConfigurationChanged" is not called in another class

Tags: android

I have a relative Layout that covers almost the whole device screen. When I change my cellphone orientation the relative layout width becomes its height and vice versa. I tried to implement the onConfigurationChanged in another class (it can't be at the main activity) to change its width and height manually, but it's not called. Here's the implementation:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
       // I'd change its width and height here...
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
       // ... and here.
    }

}
```

I also put this in the manifest.xml file:

```
<activity
        android:name="br.com.dialogscreator.MySecondActivity"
        android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" >
</activity>
```

Am I missing anything? Here's an image of what happens to my relative layout:

[image: RelativeLayout]

Thank you for now!

Comment: `onConfigurationChanged` only gets called on the currently visible activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With [Tenfour04](https://stackoverflow.com/users/506796/tenfour04)'s tip, I created a flag in the mainActivity to know the screen orientation in every class. See below how I did it:

```
public static boolean isScreenPortrait;

@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
        isScreenPortrait = true;
    } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
        isScreenPortrait = false;
    }
}
```

Then, when I need, I can call the flag from another class, for example:

```
if (MainActivity.isPortrait) { // Do what you want when the screen orientation is portrait.
```

Comment: A better approach would be to store the device orientation state using ```SharedPreferences```. Static variables might not always work the way you'd expect them to in Android activities.